# How to create elementor blocks with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, elementor

I'm having difficulties creating new Elementor blocks (images that I populate from a URL and slot into a column, in this case) from Javascript.

I currently have scripts in my page using the html block, and I have actions set up for when a button is clicked. However, I've been unable to find an example of generating new elementor blocks on a web page via code.

Is there a good example I can look at to do this?

My apologies if this is a newbie question.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1) When a button is clicked, clear the rest of the page

2) Generate a new grouping column with 4 sections

3) Create 1 image block within each section of the columns

4) Populate each image block with an image from a URL

Thanks in advance!

```
<script> 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    jQuery('.ShowAllImages').click(function(){ 
        ShowAllImages();
    });
});

function ShowAllImages() {
    //Clear the page below the button
    //Create x amount of grouping sections within page
    //Create y new elementor images in those sections
    //Populate those y elementor image blocks with images   
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also suggest Jon Skeet's [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). It's fine if it's a "newbie" question but we need enough information to help you. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: I added more information. Is that good?

Comment: Please refer to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link above.

Comment: Updated. Please confirm usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you if you want to clear the page I recommend you to use a main div or section with an unique ID

```
<section id="main">
    <div id="mySections" class="row"> </div>
</section>
```

So then you append or remove your content here if I understood you want 4 sections you can use bootstrap or your own css classes to do that example in bootstrap:

```
(function (){
function ShowAllImages() {
  clear();
  addImages();
}
function clear() {
    let parent = document.getElementById('main');
    let child = document.getElementById('mySections');
    parent.removeChild(child);
}
function addImages () {
    let parent = document.getElementById('main');
    let child1 = document.createElement('div');
    child1.classList.add('col-md-3');
    let child2 = document.createElement('div');
    child2.classList.add('col-md-3');
    let child3 = document.createElement('div');
    child3.classList.add('col-md-3');
    let child4 = document.createElement('div');
    child4.classList.add('col-md-3');

    // then you can add your images in each section with

    let img1 = document.createElement('img');
    child1.appendChild(img1);

    // ... 
    parent.appendChild(child1);
    parent.appendChild(child2);
    parent.appendChild(child3);
    parent.appendChild(child4);
}
}())
```

I don't know how you obtain the images but hope it helps, of course you can improve this.

Comment: That definitely helps. Thank you very much. I'll be obtaining these images from a URL based on an array that I get back from somewhere else. These should be able to be easily slotted in, I would think.

Comment: I realize that Elementor blocks aren't necessarily unique, they're just styling of traditional tags. For some reason, I was thinking they were unique Elementor elements. My bad.